# Erro TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

Este é meu código:

```
### BIBLIOTECAS

import scipy.special as sps
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import scipy as sp
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import gamma
from math import exp
import operator
import csv


########################################

############### GERAR VALORES DA DISTRIBUIO GE ################

def rge(n, alpha, beta):
    u = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=n)
    x = -beta * np.log((-1 / alpha) * np.log(u))
    return (x)


teste = rge(100, 1, 3)
plt.hist(teste)
plt.show()

temp = pd.DataFrame(teste)


########################################

### FUNCAO DE DISTRIBUICAO

#   t[0] = alfa
#   t[1] = beta

def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        prod *= (t[0] / t[1]) * exp(- (x[i] / t[1])) * exp(-t[0] * exp(-(x[i] / t[1])))
    return prod

##########################################

##### FUNCAO DE VEROSSIMILHANCA


def L(x, t):
    return fx(x, t)

##########################################

### FUNCAO MCMC

def mcmc(N, k={"t0": 1, "t1": 1}, x=[]):
    chute = {"t0": [1], "t1": [1]}
    M = chute
    hiper = {"t0": [0.1, 0.1], "t1": [0.1, 0.1]}  # VALORES DOS HIPERPARAMETROS
    contador = {"t0": [], "t1": []}  # CONTADOR PARA TAXA DE ACEITACAO

    thetas = M.keys()
    for i in range(N - 1):
        for j in thetas:

            if j == "t0":

                M[j].append(np.random.gamma(shape=M[j][-1], scale=k[j]))

                lista = [[M[l][-1] for l in thetas], [M[l][-1] if l != j else M[l][-2] for l in thetas]]
                t1 = gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a=hiper[j][0], scale=hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[0]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-2],
                                                                                                           a=M[j][-1],
                                                                                                           scale=k[j])
                t2 = gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a=hiper[j][0], scale=hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[1]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-1],

                                                                                                           loc=M[j][-2],
                                                                                                           scale=k[j])
                teste = (t1 / t2)

            else:

                M[j].append(np.random.gamma(shape=M[j][-1], scale=k[j]))

                lista = [[M[l][-1] for l in thetas], [M[l][-1] if l != j else M[l][-2] for l in thetas]]
                t1 = gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a=hiper[j][0], scale=hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[0]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-2],
                                                                                                           a=M[j][-1],
                                                                                                           scale=k[j])
                t2 = gamma.pdf(M[j][-2], a=hiper[j][0], scale=hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[1]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-1],
                                                                                                           a=M[j][-2],
                                                                                                           scale=k[j])

                teste = (t1 / t2)

            if (min(1, teste) < np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1)) or (np.isinf(teste)) or (np.isnan(teste)):
                M[j][-1] = M[j][-2]
                contador[j].append(0)
            else:
                contador[j].append(1)

    print("Tamanho do theta 0 : " + str(len(M["t0"])))
    print("\nTamanho do theta 1 : " + str(len(M["t1"])))

    M = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(M)
    contador = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(contador)
    cont = contador.apply(sum)
    print(cont)

    return (M)


N = int(input("Entre com o N: "))

MP = mcmc(N=N, x=temp)

print(MP)
```

E está gerando o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karlla/Documentos/Documentos/Mestrado/2° semestre/Estatistica computacional /Trabalho-artigo2/gerar.py", line 116, in <module>
    MP = mcmc(N=N, x=temp)
  File "/home/karlla/Documentos/Documentos/Mestrado/2° semestre/Estatistica computacional /Trabalho-artigo2/gerar.py", line 74, in mcmc
    t1 = gamma.pdf(M[j][-1], a=hiper[j][0], scale=hiper[j][1]) * L(x, lista[0]) * gamma.pdf(M[j][-2],
  File "/home/karlla/Documentos/Documentos/Mestrado/2° semestre/Estatistica computacional /Trabalho-artigo2/gerar.py", line 53, in L
    return fx(x, t)
  File "/home/karlla/Documentos/Documentos/Mestrado/2° semestre/Estatistica computacional /Trabalho-artigo2/gerar.py", line 44, in fx
    prod *= (t[0] / t[1]) * exp(- (x[i] / t[1])) * exp(-t[0] * exp(-(x[i] / t[1])))
  File "/home/karlla/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 78, in wrapper
    "{0}".format(str(converter)))
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <type 'float'>
```

Não estou conseguindo arrumar isso.

Comment: De onde está a vir esse n? e o t?

Comment: O n é o tamanho de temp (que são dados que eu gerei). Vou colocar o código completo.

Comment: Quando for assim, por favor, POnha o stacktrace da mensgaem de erro inteiro - note que nele está listada qual linha de cada função está sendo executada no momento do erro - como você colou só a última parte, só vemos  onde ocorreu o erro dentro do pacote do Pandas  - mas o erro aconteceu lá por que você  mandou dados inesperados para uma função do Pandas.

Comment: Tudo bem, desculpas. Já coloquei a mensagem de erro inteira.

Answer (score 5):

O erro que está ocorrendo deve-se ao fato de que você está usando um objeto [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) do Pandas e não uma lista de valores (no conteúdo da variável `x`). Se você colocar, logo ali no começo da função `mcmc` o seguinte:

```
print(x)
```

Verá como resultado algo do tipo (no teste eu usei N = 5):

```
Entre com o N: 5
            0
0   -1.056996
1    2.015035
2    1.401659
3    3.210307
..        ...
98   5.822160
99  -4.474483

[100 rows x 1 columns]
```

Ou seja, a sua variável `x` é um DataFrame com 100 linhas e 1 coluna. A coluna tem rótulo (*label*) `0` (que aparece logo ali no começo sobre a coluna), de forma que quando você faz `x[i]` (no cálculo dentro da função `fx`) você está tentando pegar a coluna de rótulo `i`. O seu código daria erro quando o `i` fosse diferente de 0, mas já está dando erro no começo porque você está tentando usar toda a coluna `x[0]` (faça `print(x[0])` e você vai perceber que ele retorna toda a coluna) no lugar de um valor real esperado (isto é, um `float`).

Ou seja, tente trocar no seu código para o seguinte:

```
def fx(x, t):
    prod = 1.0
    for i in range(0, len(x)):
        prod *= (t[0] / t[1]) * exp(- (x[0][i] / t[1])) * exp(-t[0] * exp(-(x[0][i] / t[1])))
    return prod
```

> Note o uso de `x[0][i]` (isto é, o valor na posição `i` da única
>   coluna `0`) ao invés de `x[i]`.

Depois de "corrigir" isso, o seu código dá outro erro mais pra frente (ele reclama que na linha com `t2 = gamma.pdf ...` você não está informando o argumento obrigatório `a`), mas funciona (isto é, executa sem erros - não sei se produz o resultado que você deseja).

Enfim, se vc vai usar DataFrame, use-o corretamente, ou converta-o para uma lista fazendo (e, nesse caso, o seu código em `fx` pode ser mantido como originalmente):

```
MP = mcmc(N=N, x=temp[0].tolist())
```